# Change of Variable involve derivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let me just give the 1-D version of my problem. 
Let $u\in C_c^\infty(R)$ and define $u_r(x):=u(rx)$. Then I am trying to evaluate the integration $\int_R u_r'(x)dx$. Here is my steps:
$$\int_R u_r'(x)dx = \int_R \frac{d}{dx}(u(rx))dx = \int_R u_x(rx)\cdot r dx$$
The above steps are just chain rule, no problem. Now, I wish to use substitution $y=rx$ and I have
$$\int_R u_r'(x)dx = \int_R u_x(rx)\cdot r dx = \int_R u_x(y)dy$$
However, I think I shouldn't stop here. I, in addition, compute
$$ \int_R u_x(y)dy = \int_R\frac{d}{dx}u(y)dy = \int_R\frac{d}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}u(y)dy=r\int_R\frac{d}{dy}u(y)dy = r\int_Ru'(y)dy$$
Therefore, finally I have
$$\int_R u'_r(x)dx = r\int_Ru'(y)dy$$
However, the book has answer
$$\int_R u'_r(x)dx = \int_Ru'(y)dy,$$
which is the second equation i got above.

I can't understand the answer and I don't understand where I made the mistake. Any help is really welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with you making the substitution/applying the chain rule twice.

Just start with

$$\int_Ru_r'(x) dx = \int_Ru'(rx) dx$$

and then apply your substitution $y=rx$:

$$ = \int_R \cfrac{d}{dx}u(y) d(y/r) = \int_R \cfrac{d}{dy}\cfrac{dy}{dx}u(y) d(y/r) = \cfrac{r}{r} \int_R \cfrac{d}{dy}u(y) dy = \int_R u'(y) dy$$

In your initial line of integrals, your function $u_r$ is already a function of $x$ so there is no need to apply the chain rule.  You're applying the chain rule as if it is a separate function wrt $y=rx$.